# d3 - label placement for a nested pie chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts

I'd like to place labels similar to what the image below illustrates. This might be a 2 questions in 1 sort of thing, sorry for that.

[image]

Tried 2 different approaches.

An inappropriate one, starting from a circle, draw each segment independently and rely on the way data's sorted and a property labelled `parent` to identify a segment within a chunk (main/bigger segment). This way, I can't easily place labels according to the main segment's place in the circle and it does not feel natural datawise.

https://jsfiddle.net/raven0us/c2jtsv4m/

A more appropriate one, have chunks (main segments) and inner chunks as children, this way, I can use `centroid` and place labels accordingly. Moreover, things seem natural, but I can't figure out how to draw multiple inner segments within the main segment so it looks like the chart in my previous attempt.

https://jsfiddle.net/raven0us/1v9mtdjL/

Data is mocked at the beginning of each script, `console.log(data)` before the `colors` array to see the exact structure of the data that I want to illustrate.

Comment: The first chart assumes that all the segments are 1/12 of the pie -- that somewhat limits the data that you can put in it! Is that correct?

Comment: I can't guarantee data size, the only guaranteed thing is that each segment will have the very same number of subsegments, 12 * 6 in this case, but could be 10 * 8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The layout that you have already is dependent on your data being uniform, which doesn't happen in the real world, so I found a data set and used it to create a pie chart that doesn't require perfect data.

It's a mix of the first and second charts. I have added copious comments to the code so please look through and check that you understand what is happening. I've put a demo at https://bl.ocks.org/ialarmedalien/1e453ed9b148be442f50e06ad7eb3759, so you can see the data input there.

```
function chart(id) {
  // this reads in the CSV file
  d3.csv('morley3.csv').then( data => {

    // this massages the data I'm using into a more suitable form for your chart
    // we have 12 runs with 6 experiments in each.
    // each datum is of the form 
    // { Run: <number>, Expt: <number>, Speed: <number> }
    const filteredData = data
        .filter( d => d.Run < 13 )
        .map( d => { return { Run: +d.Run, Expt: +d.Expt, Speed: +d.Speed } } )

    // set up the chart
    const width = 800,
    height = 800,
    radius = Math.min(height, width) * 0.5 - 100,
    // how far away from the chart the labels should be
    labelOffset = 10,

    svg = d3.select(id).append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height),

    g = svg.append("g")
        .attr("transform", `translate(${width/2}, ${height/2})`),

    // this will be used to generate the pie segments
    arc = d3.arc()
      .outerRadius(radius)
      .innerRadius(0),

    // group the data by the run number
    // this results in 12 groups of six experiments
    // the nested data has the form
    // [ { key: <run #>, values: [{ Run: 1, Expt: 1, Speed: 958 }, { Run: 1, Expt: 2, Speed: 869 } ... ],
    //   { key: 2, values: [{ Run: 2, Expt: 1, Speed: 987 },{ Run: 2, Expt: 2, Speed: 809 } ... ],
    // etc.
    nested = d3.nest()
      .key( d => +d.Run )
      .entries(filteredData),

    chunkSize = nested[0].values.length,

    // d3.pie() is the pie chart generator
    pie = d3.pie()
      // the size of each slice will be the sum of all the Speed values for each run
      .value( d => d3.sum( d.values, function (e) { return e.Speed } ) )
      // sort by run #
      .sort( (a,b) => a.key - b.key )
      (nested)


    // bind the data to the DOM. Add a `g` for each run
    const runs = g.selectAll(".run")
      .data(pie, d => d.key )
      .enter()
      .append("g")
      .classed('run', true)
      .each( d => {
        // run the pie generator on the children
        // d.data.values is all the experiments in the run, or in pie terms,
        // all the experiments in this piece of the pie. We're going to use 
        // `startAngle` and `endAngle` to specify that we're only generating
        // part of the pie. The values for `startAngle` and `endAngle` come
        // from using the pie chart generator on the run data.

        d.children = d3.pie()
        .value( e => e.Speed )
        .sort( (a,b) => a.Expt - b.Expt )
        .startAngle( d.startAngle )
        .endAngle( d.endAngle )
        ( d.data.values )
      })

    // we want to label each run (rather than every single segment), so
    // the labels get added next.
    runs.append('text')
      .classed('label', true)
      // if the midpoint of the segment is on the right of the pie, set the
      // text anchor to be at the start. If it is on the left, set the text anchor
      // to the end.
      .attr('text-anchor', d => {
        d.midPt = (0.5 * (d.startAngle + d.endAngle))
        return d.midPt < Math.PI ? 'start' : 'end'
      } )
      // to calculate the position of the label, I've taken the mid point of the
      // start and end angles for the segment. I've then used d3.pointRadial to
      // convert the angle (in radians) and the distance from the centre of 
      // the circle/pie (pie radius + labelOffset) into cartesian coordinates.
      // d3.pointRadial returns [x, y] coordinates
      .attr('x', d => d3.pointRadial( d.midPt, radius + labelOffset )[0] )
      .attr('y', d => d3.pointRadial( d.midPt, radius + labelOffset )[1] )
      // If the segment is in the upper half of the pie, move the text up a bit
      // so that the label doesn't encroach on the pie itself
      .attr('dy', d => {
        let dy = 0.35;
        if ( d.midPt < 0.5 * Math.PI || d.midPt > 1.5 * Math.PI ) {
          dy -= 3.0;
        }
        return dy + 'em'
      })
      .text( d => {
        return 'Run ' + d.data.key + ', experiments 1 - 6'
      })
      .call(wrap, 50)

    // now we can get on to generating the sub segments within each main segment.
    // add another g for each experiment     
    const expts = runs.selectAll('.expt')
      // we already have the data bound to the DOM, but we want the d.children,
      // which has the layout information from the pie chart generator
      .data( d => d.children )
      .enter()
      .append('g')
      .classed('expt', true)

    // add the paths for each sub-segment
    expts.append('path')
      .classed('speed-segment', true)
      .attr('d', arc)
    // I simplified this slightly to use one of the built-in d3 colour schemes
    // my data was already numeric so it was easy to use the run # as the colour
      .attr('fill', (d,i) => {
        const c = i / chunkSize,
        color = d3.rgb( d3.schemeSet3[ d.data.Run - 1 ] );

        return c < 1 ? color.brighter(c*0.5) : color;
      })
      // add a title element that appears when mousing over the segment
      .append('title')
      .text(d => 'Run ' + d.data.Run + ', experiment ' + d.data.Expt + ', speed: ' + d.data.Speed )

    // add the lines
    expts.append('line')
      .attr('y2', radius)
      // assign a class to each line so we can control the stroke, etc., using css
      .attr('class', d => {
        return 'run-' + d.data.Run + ' expt-' + d.data.Expt
      })
      // convert the angle from radians to degrees
      .attr("transform", d => {
        return "rotate(" + (180 + d.endAngle * 180 / Math.PI) + ")";
      });

    function wrap(text, width) {
        text.each(function () {
            let text = d3.select(this),
                words = text.text().split(/\s+/).reverse(),
                word,
                line = [],
                lineNumber = 0,
                lineHeight = 1.2, // ems
                tfrm = text.attr('transform')
                y = text.attr("y"),
                x = text.attr("x"),
                dy = parseFloat(text.attr("dy")),
                tspan = text.text(null).append("tspan")
                .attr("x", x)
                .attr("y", y)
                .attr("dy", dy + "em");

            while (word = words.pop()) {
                line.push(word);
                tspan.text(line.join(" "));
                if (tspan.node().getComputedTextLength() > width) {
                    line.pop();
                    tspan.text(line.join(" "));
                    line = [word];
                    tspan = text.append("tspan")
                    .attr("x", x)
                    .attr("y", y)
                    .attr("dy", ++lineNumber * lineHeight + dy + "em")
                        .text(word);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    return svg;
  })
}

chart('#chart');
```

Comment: This is great, it's exactly what I had in mind, but did not have the expertise to execute it properly. Thanks for taking the time to do this, will have a thorough look at it tomorrow.

Comment: The blocks demo shows a white screen with only labels arranged around a circle.

Comment: Got one more question, what if I wanted to have like a grid under each segment with values from 1 - 15 and colour that based on the value it holds instead of colouring the whole segment (according to my first fiddle, which is hardcoded to 10, but could be anything in a predefined range)? It's like prematurely cutting the path. Will have a double bounty for this, you guys were helpful.

Comment: Can you create another question for that? A little diagram of what you want to achieve would also be useful.

Comment: @jrook blocks demo is back to full colour glory

Comment: I got it, altered / added some stuff to your script and it got me where I wanted, with a natural flow. This is how it looks now - https://i.imgur.com/i8x5TNo.png. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Ravenous, as an off-topic comment, you could use a bar chart for this. It would portray the difference between the values better.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure If I understand the question properly. But this is too long to be crammed into a comment so I wrote an answer, maybe it solves the problem.

The stated problem for the first method is:

> This way, I can't easily place labels according to the main segment's
>   place in the circle

The label placement code is:

```
labels.selectAll("text")
        .data(keys)
        .enter()
        .append("text")
        .style("text-anchor", "middle")
        .style("font-weight", "bold")
//LABEL PLACEMENT CODE
            .attr("x", (d, i) => {
                return barScale(config.max * 1.2) * Math.cos(segmentSlice * i - Math.PI / 2);
            })
            .attr("y", (d, i) => {
                return barScale(config.max * 1.2) * Math.sin(segmentSlice * i - Math.PI / 2);
            })
```

This places the lables along big segment dividing lines. We have a total of 12 segments each spanning 30 degrees. Each large segment has 6 sub-segments each one spanning 5 degrees. So it seems you only need to rotate your labels 15 degrees (3 sub-segment span) 
to place them like the picture in the question.

First convert 15 degrees to radians:

```
15 * PI / 180 = 0.261799
```

Then add the above value to the label placement code:

```
.attr("x", (d, i) => {
    return barScale(config.max * 1.2) * 
        Math.cos(segmentSlice * i - Math.PI / 2 + 0.261799); //HERE
    }).attr("y", (d, i) => {
        return barScale(config.max * 1.2) * 
           Math.sin(segmentSlice * i - Math.PI / 2 + 0.261799); //AND HERE
                })
```

Here is the updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fha19jtm/

And all the labels are placed like the given picture. The data property can also be used to change the rotation angle based on the combination of large/small segments. This way, the placement of each label can be fine-tuend to the desired amount.

Comment: Thanks, that does help, will adapt it for dynamic data (undefined number of segments and subsegments). I'm also interested in following the second approach as it seems more natural to me or at least learn how to draw the subsegments within the large one. I know this should go in another question, but they are the same thing/related.

Comment: You can always overlap the two charts. Draw the large segments and small segments separately over each other.

Comment: Yeah, but am I able to keep it natural DOMwise (in terms of nodes) and data flow? Just a novice @ d3 and SVGs, something like select `.chunks`, `each()`, draw 6x `.inner`?

Comment: I really prefer the approach I suggested here since I believe it is more customizable. But I don't see any problem in first joining the outer array and draw the large segments and then joining the whole array (maybe concatenate all segments) and draw small segments next.